# 33 водителей или 33 водителя?

Tags: грамотная-речь, числительные

Как правильно: За первый квартал сотрудники ГИБДД выявили 33 пьяных водителей(так в газете) или водителя на дорогах города.

Comment: "В мёде содержатся 180 полезных питательных веществ, витаминов, макро- и микроэлементов, протеинов, органических кислот. - акцент на каждом виде полезных веществ, каждый из перечня элементов содержимого важен."

Это - ответ на Ваш вопрос о мёде, и применительно к пьяным водителям он также вполне подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае корректно мн.ч.Так как речь идет не об одной дороги, а о разных.И поймали их не вместе, а по отдельности. Здесь акцент ставится на раздельность действий каждого действующего лица, называемого подлежащим, а также подчеркнуто активность действующих лиц.
Ср.: За первый квартал ГИБДД выявила 33 пьяных водителя на дороге города.

Водителей поймали вместе.

Дополнение

> При существительных мужского и среднего рода, зависящих от числительных два, три, четыре (а также от составных числительных, оканчивающихся на указанные цифры), определение, находящееся между числительным и существительным, в современном языке ставится, как правило, в форме родительного падежа множественного числа: два высоких дома, три больших окна, двадцать четыре деревянных стола. Например: ...**Офицеры ели жадно, без разговоров, наверстывали за два потерянных в боях дня (Шолохов);**    **Два крайних окна в первом этаже закрыты изнутри газетными листами... (А.Н. Толстой)**.
>
> Составные количественные числительные, оканчивающиеся на **два, три, четыре**, при склонении сохраняют в винительном падеже форму именительного даже в тех случаях, когда с ними сочетаются названия одушевлённых предметов: **избрать тридцать три представителя, принять двадцать четыре посетителя, выдвинуть сто сорок два кандидата**.
> Справочник по литературному редактированию текста. Д.Э. Розенталь.

Comment: Я согласна: сотрудники выявили, но 33 водителей как-то неправильно, лучше 33 водителя.Тогда: ГИБДД выявила (инспекция)33 пьяных водителя- получается при такой сочетаемости, что их поймали вместе,значит, надо 33 водителей?

Comment: @Верьясова,  числительные 2,3,4, а также составные числительные числительные на 2,3,4 в косвенных падежах согласуются с существительными.

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы: в этом случае корректно ед.ч. См.дополнение к ответу.

Answer (score 4):

33, 34 пьяных водителя, но 35, 36 пьяных водителей